Fourier transform in finite range
I know that the Fourier transform applies to infinite intervals $(-\infty,+\infty)$:
$$\hat{f}(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\exp\left(-2\pi kxi \right) \mathrm d x$$
I would like to see if there is something similar for a finite interval $[0,a]$.
From this book (Integral Transforms and Their Applications), I learned about the Finite Fourier Sine and Cosine Transforms:
$$\tilde{f}_s(n)=\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\sin\left(\dfrac{n\pi x}{a} \right)\mathrm d x$$ and $$\tilde{f}_c(n)=\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\cos\left(\dfrac{n\pi x}{a} \right)\mathrm d x,$$
where $n\in\mathbb{N}^\ast$.
I was wondering if there is a Fourier transform over a finite interval $[0,\alpha]$, similar to those, but not sine or cosine-based. I was thinking of something like the following:
$$\tilde{f}(n)=\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\exp\left(\dfrac{n\pi x}{a}i \right)\mathrm d x$$
Does anyone know if such a thing exists? Could someone provide me with a bibliographic reference?
Thank you in advance!

Well, if I am not wrong, $$\hat{f}(k) = \hat{f_c}(k) + i\hat{f_s}(k)$$ Also such a thing probably 'does' exist; but I am unsure of its utility

Fourier series coefficients are derived from Fourier transforms over a finite range which can be $0<x<P$ where $P$ is the period (see Eq, 7 at Exponential form coefficients). Also, the Fourier transform of a rectangle function of height $h$ and width $a$ centered around $x=\frac{a}{2}$ is $\int\limits_0^a h, e^{-2 \pi i \omega x} , dx=\frac{i h \left(e^{-2 i \pi a \omega}-1\right)}{2 \pi \omega}$.

But why $0<x<a$? The relationship between the Fourier transform and Fourier sin and cosine transforms is for even functions $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x), e^{-2 i \pi \omega x} , dx=2 \int_0^{\infty} f(x), \cos(2 \pi \omega x) , dx,,\quad f(-x)=f(x)$$ and for odd functions $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x), e^{-2 i \pi \omega x} , dx=-2 i \int\limits_0^{\infty} f(x), \sin(2 \pi \omega x) , dx,,\quad f(-x)=-f(x)$$ so it seems to me it'd be more natural to ask about truncated Fourier transforms where the interval is centered around the origin.

@Kraken , yes, what you’re saying is correct. That’s how I also thought about the form of $\tilde{f}(n)$, which uses the exponential function. I just wanted to check if there’s any related literature, so I can avoid deriving the rules myself or searching through various books on Fourier series.

@StevenClark , I understand that the text uses Fourier coefficients (slightly modified) as a transformation. From this perspective, it makes sense that $0$ is not the center of symmetry for the interval, since it’s sufficient for us to be within any interval of a period $a$. However, what sets this approach apart more fundamentally is the absence of $2$ within the $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms. What I want to find out is if there’s any relevant literature so I can look up related rules and a corresponding approach.

The Fourier exponential, $\sin$, and $\cos$ transforms are more generally defined as
$$\hat{f}(\omega)=c(a,b) \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x), e^{i b \omega x} , dx\tag{1},$$
$$\hat{f}_s(\omega)=2, c(a,b) \int\limits_0^{\infty} f(x) \sin(b \omega x) , dx\tag{2},$$
and
$$\hat{f}_c(\omega)=2, c(a,b) \int\limits_0^{\infty} f(x) \cos(b \omega x) , dx\tag{3}$$
where
$$c(a,b)=\sqrt{\frac{|b|}{(2 \pi)^{1-a}}}\tag{4}$$
so the presence of $2$ is merely a consequence of the selection the Fourier parameter $b$.

In the formulas in my earlier comments I assumed ${a,b}={0,-2 \pi}$, but setting $b=\pi$ eliminates the $2$.

The relationship $$\frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{-a}^a f(x), e^{i \frac{\pi n x}{a}} , dx=\int_\limits0^a f(x), \cos\left(\frac{\pi n x}{a}\right) , dx+i \int\limits_0^a f(x), \sin\left(\frac{\pi n x}{a}\right) , dx$$ further illustrates my point that for the finite Fourier transform the interval should be centered around the origin.

@StevenClark Maybe you're right. I just cited the definition I saw in this book (https://www.libristo.gr/el/bivlio/integral-transforms-and-their-applications_06698097?gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiAlsy5BhDeARIsABRc6ZtaRPAoqNiZCTgjSYnYCtm6mgpeY3MVT73MiocoNJuEXT0zrAldsdcaAsplEALw_wcB page 436) and this one (https://www.amazon.com/Fourier-Transforms-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486685225 page 72).
Anyway, I did my work by treating the Fourier coefficients as a transform. Thanks for your time!
